# Extract a specific a reference id from a URL

Tags: url, google-sheets

How can I extract a reference id from a URL to display in another column on Google Spreadsheets? 
The URL is: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/1208668091/?eBP=NotAvailableFromVoyagerAPI&refId=272d49e6-406a-4596-8720-f2287fb99331&trk=d_flagship3_search_srp_jobs

And in that exemple, I want to extract: `1208668091`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhkx2.png

Comment: Welcome. Do you want to use a formula or a script?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the url is in A1, see if this works

```
=regexextract(A1, "/(\d+)/")
```

Depending on your locale, you may have to change the comma with a semi-colon.